# How to create a POST request in Apps script?

Tags: post, google-apps-script

My objective is to use the upload attachment functionality of the Gmail API. The uploaded file is to be processed within my Gmail add-on. I found the following POST request [in this link](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/uploads#simple).

POST https://www.googleapis.com/upload/gmail/v1/users/userId/messages/send?uploadType=media

Here is my try so far:

```
function testPOST() {
  Logger.log('Testing of POST in Apps script');
//  var url = ScriptApp.getService().getUrl();
  var url = "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/gmail/v1/users/userId/messages/send"
  Logger.log('URL:'+url);

  var options =
      {
        "method"  : "POST",
        "uploadType" : "media"
      };

  // Trying to fetch the file
  var result = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
  Logger.log('Response code: ' + result.getResponseCode());    

  // maybe I need to use some function in 'Gmail.Users.*'
  }
```

Comment: Is this information useful for your situation? https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/send By the way, you want to sent an email with UrlFetchApp without using Gmail API of Advanced Google services. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. In fact, within my Gmail add-on, I want to upload a file to be processed. I am trying to use the upload attachment function of the Gmail API to achieve my objective. In the link you provided there is an example in javascript which uses 'gapi.client.gmail.users.message.send' to create the POST request to send a message. I believe I need something similar for the upload POST request. I edited my post to make it more clear.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, I cannot see the vision of your goal yet. I apologize for this. About the attachment file, where is retrieved from? And do you want to send an email using Gmail API?

Comment: Hey @mtleis Why are you using `UrlFetchApp`? Is there any reason you prefer to use it other than the [`GmailApp`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app) class or the [`Gmail`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/gmail) advanced service?

Comment: @Tanaike, I hope I could explain it better. I want the user of my Gmail add-on to be able to upload a file from his local machine. I thought that I could use the functionality of the Gmail API to allow the user to upload a file. I have no intention of sending the file as attachment, but rather to read information from within the file. The read information will be used to create new emails.

Comment: Hey @carlesgg97, There is no reason for using UrlFetchApp. I am still trying to figure out whether I could use a POST request to allow a user to upload a file, using the gmail api.

Comment: Thank you for replying. You want to upload a file from the local PC and retrieve the file content from the uploaded file. If my understanding is correct, I think that Users.messages: send of Gmail API is not suitable for it. For example, I think that Web Apps and/or Drive API is required to be used. But when this is used for Gmail add-on, I think that it might be required to separate the upload process and the use of file content.